# Get solution details from running debugger in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm working on a tool which will check a configuration file for a large system.

In order to do this, I want to look for all references to a particular method (the one responsible for loading a value from the config object), and check that all the parameters from each instance of the call are present in the config object and are permissible for loading on a named system.

The config file is only ever created by one application, which will be run from a known directory. It reflects all DLLs in the directory to return all instances of the method call which loads a property in order to create a list of all properties used by the system for validation.

This approach works when running from the installation directory, however durning development, I will need to run the tool from the IDE.

When running from the IDE, I want to find the name of the open solution file so that I can retrieve the subordinate projects and get all references to the config object.

Is it possible to get the name of the solution file from an instance of the debugger running in the IDE (VS2013 in this case).

Or, as an alternative, is there a suitable API call which will return the name of the open solution from VS?
This will only be called if there is a debugger attached, so will therefore be running in a `vshost` wrapper.

Comment: The 'Solution' is irrelevant - it's just a collection of projects, which compile into assemblies. The runtime doesn't know, nor care about the sln file.

Comment: I get that, but in order to load the assemblies and look for references, I need to know which ones to load. When the application is installed, it all lives in a single folder so I can iterate all the binaries and reflect them to find the calls. Can you suggest a way to do the same in the IDE while debugging, given that I don't know where the DLLs will end up without knowing which projects are in the 'collection of projects'? The debugger runs in the IDE, the solution is open, so there must be a way to know where the sources are otherwise how can a breakpoint match up to a line in the source?

Comment: PDB files - they relate to the currently loaded assembly. (not solution)

Comment: Ok, in which case I'll have to approach this a different way. Is there a way to get the name of the active solution file using a VS api call? Short of having to predefine a list of all classes which I pass to the application, I'm a bit lost as to how to go about this. An alternative would be to create a tree of all assemblies, but several are only used in one or two projects, and there are no projects in the solution common to all other projects.

Comment: I've tried approaching this via `AppDomain` but as not all assemblies in the solution are loaded, I'm drawing a blank

Comment: so your tool and all required assemblies/projects are part of one solution, right? and what exactly do you want to know at debugging time?

Comment: The tool will look for any calls to a particular method `GetParameter()[ParamName]` to produce a list of all values for `ParamName` which appear in every project in the solution. It will then check the config object to see if that parameter exists, and whether it can be loaded on that particular machine. This works fine using reflection when everything is installed, as I just iterate over all the binaries in the directory, but as they are all in different folders when built from the IDE, I need a way to do the same thing without a complete list of all binaries beforehand.

Comment: why don't you copy the required binaries to your output folder using a PreBuildEvent e.g.  or use mock projects in your solution?

Comment: @Siraf I did ponder that, with the idea to use another project which depends on everything else and copies all binaries to a known folder. I'd hoped to avoid that if possible as any new projects would have to be manually added as references, but it looks like there's no other way to do it

Comment: @Siraf That was the tip I needed, thanks. I've created a separate project which has a dependency on all other projects other than the validation tool, and it reflects all the dependencies. If you could post an answer to the effect of your comment, I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the required binaries to your output folder using a PreBuildEvent e.g. or use mock projects in your solution.